# Manager news or manager's news

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I am setting a label for news only visible to managers.

The two suggestions I have for phrasing is

- Manager news
- Manager's news

The second one feels intuitively wrong, but I googled a bit and found that the 's could be possessive for singular nouns.

Can anyone explain if I am correct and in that case why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Manager's news" refers to the news by, from, or belonging to a single manager;  His or her news, in other words.

"Managers' news" refers to news by, from, or belonging to multiple managers.

Are you limited to two words? I suggest "News for Managers" as unambiguous and not requiring the possessive apostrophe.

One could also use the plural in a non-possessive sense: "Managers News" (news for managers, in other words). To me, it doesn't feel quite as right. No one but a persnickety copy editor would notice, though.

Comment: I like the last option the best. Is "Manager news" completely incorrect also?

Comment: I would not say completely incorrect, but it is singular. A more "plural" wording is "Management News" -- information for people in management, that is, managers -- plural.